# How to change location of .flair directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using flair for sentiment analysis and it's datasets. The datasets for flair are quite large in size and are currently installed on my quite small SSD in my user folder. Is there anyway that I can move the .flair folder from my user folder on my SSD to my other drive without breaking anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When importing datasets into flair, one can specify a custom path to import from. Copy the flair datasets to a folder you choose on your larger harddrive and then specify that path when loading a dataset.

flair.datasets.WASSA_FEAR(data_folder="E:/flair_datasets/")